# Matlab compilation to excel add-in work but lead to unusable function

Tags: excel, matlab

I wrote a function (anticancer.m) in matlab (R2014a) to do a non-linear regression from a set of data. The fitted equation is another function (sig.m):

```
function y=sig(a,b,c,d,x)
    if nargin<5
        error('La fonction nécessiste cinq arguments');
    end
    y=(d+(a-d)./(1+(x./c).^b));
end
```

So, the function sig is used somewere in the anticancer function:

```
37: ft = fittype('sig(a,b,c,d,x)');
```

The function is working perfectly in matlab. My problem is when i compile this function to make an excel add-in. I did included both the anticancer.m and sig.m file in the deploy tool. The compilation process don't gives any error. The function sig is working fine in excel. But the function anticancer return an error:

> "Error in sigmo.sigmoclass.1_0: Undefined function 'fittype' for input
>   arguments of type 'char'.Error in => anticancer.m at line 37"

Can someone help me!

N.B.: The function 'fittype' is part of the curve fitting toolbox, which should be supported by the compiler (http://www.mathworks.fr/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the compiler and can't access the documentation. Are there any additional steps that need to be taken to include functions that are not part of the base MATLAB install? `fittype` is part of the Curve Fitting Toolbox.

Comment: It's possible that the Curve Fit Toolbox is not supported for compiling

Comment: The Curve fitting toolbox is supported by the compiler but it may not be included by default. Try to include the whole 'fittype' class in your project (in the deploy tool).